# Completely rerender component on router change

Tags: angular, svg

I need to rerener a component on router change, the problem is that I draw into SVG file some data.

Some code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const self = this;
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.DiagnosticServerID = params['diagnosticServerID'];
      this.ConnectionName = params['connectionName'];

      jQuery('#svgobj')[0].addEventListener('load', function () {
      _snap = Snap("#svgobj"));
      self.registerCpuUsageControllerEvent();
      svgTooltip(_snap);
      self.go();
    });
    });
  }
```

Where is the problem? The problem is on  jQuery('#svgobj')[0].addEventListener, it works only once when I use this component for the first time.

So I thougth to completely rerener the component on route change.

Don't ask why I use jQuery here and some weird code, it's just a POC and port from Ember :)

**Updated working code:**

```
 svgObj: boolean = false;
constructor(public api: ApiService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.DiagnosticServerID = params['diagnosticServerID'];
      this.ConnectionName = params['connectionName'];
      if(this.svgObj){
        this.start();
      }
    });
  }

initSvg(){
    const self = this;
    jQuery('#svgobj')[0].addEventListener('load', function () {
      self.start();
    });
  }

  start(){
    const self = this;
    _snap = Snap("#svgobj");
    self.registerCpuUsageControllerEvent();
    svgTooltip(_snap);
    self.go();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code from `ngOnInit()` to `initSvg()` and call `initSvg()` from `ngOnInit()` and subscribe to route params changes and call it from there as well:

```
constructor(activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
  activatedRoute.params.subscribe(val => this.initSvg());
}
```

Comment: Well, If I call for initSvg from constructor there is an error because there is no #svgobj yet.

Comment: In that case you need to guard against that. `if(this.svgobj) { this.initSvg(); }`